How are notes named in Japan?
We use A - G or tonic sol fa. Do the Japanese label notes differently? How was their music notated before western colonisation?

Japan was never colonized by the west nor by anyone else.  On the contrary, they colonized a number of places themselves.

The question seems to assume that there's a universal set of notes that's the same everywhere, the only question is the naming. I wouldn't be so sure about that. And the "we" ... I wonder what on this site implies that there's a self-evident commonly understood sense of we here. "We" as in music.stackexchange users?

@piiperiReinstateMonica I read "we" as "we in the English-speaking world" or perhaps more precisely "we who had our musical education in an English-speaking country."

I wonder if, say, Germany, Brazil or Romania are parts of the English-speaking world... :)

@piiperiReinstateMonica in the traditional understanding of the term, they are not.  Certainly the standard systems of music instruction in those countries use neither English pitch names nor the English language.

@phoog What note names do you think are used in Germany, Brazil or Romania? Or Bohemia, Sweden, Greece...?

@Divizna in several of those you listed it's C, D, E, F, G, A, H. B also part of the system but is the same note known as B flat for the rest of the world.

@ojs You forgot to mention "Ti" instead of "Si". But I wasn't asking what system those countries use (all can be found on Wikipedia in a minute or two), I asked what Phoog imagines they use. Since, apparently, I and everyone else from one or another of those places are not part of "we" but the exotic "other".

@Divizna I know that different note names are used in different languages.  They vary not so much by place as by language.  That is why I assume the "we" in the first sentence of this question refers to "English speakers" generally.  I must add that I don't see the point of this conversation.  If someone wants to point out that the first sentence of this question is insufficiently cosmopolitan for failing to mention explicitly that "we" is "English speakers," or whatever else it may refer to, or
any other perceived fault of the question, why not just call it out explicitly?

@phoog I think the asker meant something like "we of the general European-based tradition", not only English speakers. That's how you read it, and I wonder why. It seems oddly specific, considering the question mentions two naming systems, one of which is what's used around southern Europe, rather than in English.

@Divizna in my experience "Ti" and "Si" are mixed quite freely because switching between them doesn't change meaning. I thought it would be obvious that "English-speaking world" would exclude the countries where English is not the primary language, but we all have different ways of thinking.

@ojs The question says nothing about "English-speaking world", that's solely Phoog's interpretation. I'm questioning that interpretation.

@Divizna it also strongly implies that "we" is a group has a concept of diatonic notes, labels them from A to G and is able to write in English. The rest of the question wouldn't change if "we" were I and my neighbor's singing dog and we called the notes "woof", "wuf", "grr" etc so I don't understand why this is so important.

@Divizna I read it in one of two ways; either "we English speakers" or "we members of some group I belong to, the precise membership of which I am uncertain."  There's no need to ascribe to the asker of the question a belief that all other European languages use the same naming conventions as English.  If anyone wants to cover that possibility, a better approach would be to add a comment such as "by the way, German does it like this and Romance languages do it like that, and contrary to a common misunderstanding, Tonic Sol-Fa isn't that system."

@Divizna https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonic_sol-fa -- this is why I read the reference as a reference to English speakers.  Tonic sol-fa a is a distinctly English system.

It's an interesting question, but I feel it's not phrased appropriately.

According to Wiktionary, the Japanese have a heptatonic solfège system that uses the syllables ha, ni, ho, he, to, i, ro, corresponding to do, re, mi, fa, sol, la, ti.  The characters are ハ, ニ, ホ, ヘ, ト, イ, ロ.
According to Dolmetsch Online, the system, called iroha, dates from the 20th century:

the Japanese solfege system that was used during and after World War II at a time when it was Japanese policy to substitute Western terms with Japanese equivalents (though they were still playing and listening to Western-style music). The system started on the note A and read as follows:
i, ro, ha, ni, ho, he, to

One may infer from this that they were using the Latin-derived syllabes beforehand for European music and music written in the European system of notation.
Wikipedia is a good place to start for traditional Japanese music notation; it appears that there were a few different systems.
Another useful resource is Wikipedia's Key signature names and translations, which covers varying usage in, as of this writing, English, German, Dutch (both Belgium and the Netherlands), Japanese, Chinese, Korean, Arabic, Persian, Hebrew, Italian, French, Spanish, Portuguese, Russian, Romanian, Greek, and Lithuanian.

The Wikipedia link seems to say that at least some parts of traditional Japanese music don't even consider "notes" as in "pitch-class" as a primary aspect to notate, but other things like timbre. So talking about "the notes" might raise the question "what notes?" For some traditional Japanese instruments there are scales, but not necessarily in the same meaning as in "do-re-mi" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_musical_scales

This might be seen not as a specific musical notation, but just the application of a traditional order for the Japanese syllabary. It's more like the ABCDEFG note names than solfege.

@KarlKnechtel whether it's more like letter names or fixed do solfège, it serves the same purpose as both.

There are traditional systems of scales, chiefly pentatonic, which do not directly correspond obviously to the Western system, and notation systems for traditional instruments, which I believe are always instrument-specific (i.e. like recorder fingering charts or guitar TAB notation). But for all other music, the "Western" notation system is universal.
But for referring to notes, the simplest answer to the "Which system do they use?" question is "Most of them!" The Wikipedia article Key signature names and translations gives the "Japanese" system, based on labelling the notes from A to G with the beginning of the traditional kana order: 'i-ro-ha-ni-ho-he-to' (see Wikipedia article). This is used very widely in formal contexts to identify keys, listing symphonies, for example, on concert programmes and flyers, or on CD jackets. (More generally the i-ro-ha sequence is much less used than it once was, but everyone knows the first seven letters at least.)
Next is fixed Do, i.e. mapping A-G onto ra shi do re mi fa so (using Hepburn romanisation of the Japanese pronunciations). This is the most common way to refer to individual notes, at least in most amateur contexts, such as choral singing. Sharps and flats can be added with do-shaapu or shi-furatto and so on; but sometimes if singing something in a foreign language so that the words are not mastered yet, rather than singing to la-la-la, the choir will sing the do-re-mi note names, omitting sharps and flats. (This can get quite confusing to some of us when there are lots of accidentals and enharmonic changes.)
Movable Do is very rarely used, never in my experience. But it is known, and I have heard someone ask for confirmation "You are using fixed Do, is that right, rather than movable Do?" to which the answer was "Yes, fixed Do."
Next, perhaps because so many Japanese musicians go and study in Germany, the German system is widely used, perhaps more among professionals. This involves the basic letters A-H (B is B♭, H is B natural), plus the German suffixes for flat and sharp, so Es is E♭ and Eis is E♯ and so on. But this is not limited to professionals; apparently school wind bands, for example, tune to B♭ (not A) and this is always referred to as be.
Then in popular music, for writing guitar chords and so on, the English system is used. There is not much confusion, for example over what "B" means, because the English "B" (B-natural) is pronounced as bi while the German one is pronounced as Be (like the original; all romanisation means "pronounce the letters properly, not like English spelling), and so on through the alphabet.
So if you are an English-speaking person in Japan, unfortunately the system we use is the one you are least likely to meet.
